# Post Build event with condition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, travis-ci

[Having the need](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3993) to add a condition to the Post Build event in my Visual Studio 2013 project, I ended up with the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    <PostBuildEvent>"$(SolutionDir)..\Deploy\Build\sign-bin.cmd"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've added the condition `Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' "` manually with a text editor to the CSPROJ file.

This works as expected, my solution builds successfully both in Visual Studio as well as in [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/UweKeim/SimpleBackup).

**What doesn't work:**

When editing the Post Build event inside Visual Studio in the graphical editor, it seems to ignore the condition and simply stores the event twice:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    <PostBuildEvent>"$(SolutionDir)..\Deploy\Build\sign-bin.cmd"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"$(SolutionDir)..\Deploy\Build\sign-bin.cmd"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It doesn't matter whether I add the condition to the `<PropertyGroup>` node or the `<PostBuildEvent>` node.

In both cases the nodes are duplicated by Visual Studio upon saving.

**My questions:**

Any chance to somehow add the ability to ignore my Post Build event (which is the reason for the condition) on Travis?

Any chance to somehow tell Visual Studio to *not* duplicate the node with condition upon saving?

Comment: If you use conditions, then stop using VS to edit that part as the IDE simply could not handle it right.

Comment: ^ +1 to that. To avoid accidentally editing these events through VS you can consider another way to specify something has to happen after the build like `<Target AfterTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">....</Target>`